# Flutter firestore - update a single map entry where the key is a url

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

How to update a single map entry in a map where keys are url strings?

[image]

This map entry is one among many. I retrieve this map from Firestore and store it locally in a provider. The user then gets to change this boolean value.

I would like to update only the fields that changed.
My other option is to overwrite with the new map with altered values.
I don't like that because I can't trust unwanted changes from happening on the user side.

Now this is the first I encountered the fact the Firestore doesn't like all these special characters. I got a message to use a `FieldPath`. I used `FieldPath.fromString().toString()` but the error is the same

> Paths must not contain '~', '*', '/', '[', or ']'.
> 'package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/field_path.dart':
> Failed assertion: line 50 pos 12: '!path.contains('/')'

The code producing this error:

```
onPressed: () {
  final provider = Provider.of<MaraiMilkProvider>(context, listen: false);
  final user = CurrentUser.getCurrentUser();

  Map<String, dynamic> items = provider.items;

  DocumentReference docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(user.uid).doc('newArrivals');

  FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction(
    (tx) async {
      DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await tx.get(docRef);
      Map<String, dynamic> mapUrls = snapshot.get('mapUrls');
      Iterable<String> keys = mapUrls.keys;
      
      // I feel I'm being pedantic here, but I want to make sure I'm not overwriting a malformed url due to unexpected changes on user side.
      for (String key in keys) {
        if (items.keys.contains(key) && items[key] == true) {
          tx.update(docRef, {key: items[key]}); // Am I updating the `mapUrls` field here, or a nonexistent field
        }
      }
    },
  );
},
```

This produces the exception:

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/unknown] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Use FieldPath.of() for field names containing '~*/[]'.

`FieldPath.of()` does not exist in Flutter. `FieldPath.fromString()` exists which returns a FieldPath object. So I invoke the `toString()` method on it.
When changing the update line from

```
tx.update(docRef, {key: items[key]});
```

to

```
tx.update(docRef, {FieldPath.fromString(key).toString(): items[key]});
```

I get

> Unhandled Exception: 'package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/field_path.dart': Failed assertion: line 50 pos 12: '!path.contains('/')': Paths must not contain '~', '*', '/', '[', or ']'.

Comment: 1) Can you show the code that raises this error? 2) Can you show the code that *wrote* this key to the database?

Comment: Perhaps you can store the values in a reverse-index fashion? That is, `temp` becomes a list of objects, containing a string value `url` and a boolean value `flag`. You can then transform the list locally into a dictionary on load. If this is too computationally expensive, you could strip the special values from the string and work with that as a key (assuming you don't need to reproduce the original url)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have added the code in the post. As for the code that wrote this key to the database, I have added this code manually. I am still in the process of coming up with the flow of the app. The urls of the images will be shared by all users so I'm intending to add to the initializing process upon user registration. But for now, I'm still trying to figure how that will work.

Comment: @MikiMints If I understand you correctly, I think I will need to reproduce the url. It's of an image that the all users will need to switch on or off. Also, if by `reverse-index` you mean instead of a map for all items, I use a list of maps for each String-boolean pair, then that may be a good idea. I will need to implement and see how it goes, but I need I like the idea.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of how the data looks like while stored in the Firestore? It can be simply one sample document.

Comment: Why are you invoking `toString()` on the `FieldPath` in that last code fragment? Won't that just reproduce the original string, and thus explain the error. Can't you pass the `FieldPath` object into the call to `update()`?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug , if you use "/" in key while updating it throws an error but works perfectly when using set function.
You can use

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('user')
          .doc(docId)
          .set(data, SetOptions(merge: true))
```